# Escape characters in string exclude html tags

Tags: java, html, string, escaping

Is there any way how to escape in Java characters in string which contains html tags which i want not to escape? For example in string I have

```
<h1>a b c d ö</h1>
```

and I need to get:

```
<h1>a b c d &ouml</h1>
```

Comment: What you have tried to print this text

Comment: Have you looked at the guava HtmlEscaper? http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/html/HtmlEscapers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "a b c d ö";
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(s));
  }
```

Comment: Hi this method escapes also <ul> and <li> html tags

Answer (score 1):

**Check this:**

```
String textIn = "<h1>a b c d ö</h1>";

String textOut = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(textIn);
```

**println** textOut: `&lt;h1&gt;a b c d &ouml;&lt;/h1&gt`

**For xml or tags:**

```
String textIn = "<h1>a b c d ö</h1>";

String textOut = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(textIn));
```

**println**: textOut `<h1>a b c d &ouml;</h1>`